# How do I iterate over ALL DataProc clusters in a GCP project in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to create a google cloud function that iterates over all currently running DataProc clusters, however the `dataproc.list_functions()` method requires the region be passed in as a parameter. We have multiple clusters over multiple regions active at any one time.

Is there any way to retrieve a list of regions in Python and wrap the call to `list_functions` inside a `for` loop that iterates through all regions?

eg:

```
for region in regions:
    for cluster in client.list_clusters('project', region):
        do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can list the usable regions on a project by using the Compute client :

```
from googleapiclient import discovery

def get_regions(project):
    compute_client = discovery.build('compute', 'v1')

    regions = compute_client.regions().list(project=project).execute()

    region_names = []
    for r in regions["items"]:
        region_names.append(r["name"])

    return region_names
```

Comment: Hi @norbjd, thanks for your reply. When I try to implement this I get the following error: `Instance of 'Resource' has no 'regions' member` on this line: `regions = compute_client.regions().list(project=project).execute()`

Comment: I'm using `google-api-python-client` v.1.7.8 here and it works perfectly, could you check your version? (I have executed the code in a Docker container to be sure this is not related to my environment).

Comment: Sorry - Stackoverflow farted and I couldn't edit my comment - it was just a false positive from pylint and your solution works perfectly. Thanks!